# Checkbox with 2 values Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i want to make checkbox with 2 values - One with "Yes" and other with "No" and send to database. I try to make it when is not send "Yes" to give me "No" but now dont work. I would be grateful if you could tell me how to do it and what are the errors in my code

```
<form method="post" action="/adminpanel/hofswitch">
    @csrf
    <div class="card-body">
        @foreach($char as $value)

        <div class="card-body">
        @if($value->status == "Yes")
            <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="{{$value->id}}">
            <input type="checkbox" name="switch[]" value="Yes" checked data-bootstrap-switch data-off-color="danger" data-on-color="success">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-form-label" for="inputSuccess"><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Character Class</label>
                <input type="text" name="class" value="{{$value->class}}" class="form-control is-valid" id="inputSuccess" readonly="true" placeholder="{{$value->class}}">
            </div>
            @else
                <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="{{$value->id}}">
                <input type="checkbox" name="switch[]" value="Yes" data-bootstrap-switch data-off-color="danger" data-on-color="success">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-form-label" for="inputError"><i class="far fa-times-circle"></i> Character Class</label>
                    <input type="text" name="class" value="{{$value->class}}" class="form-control is-invalid" id="inputError" readonly="true" placeholder="{{$value->class}}">
                </div>
            @endif
        </div>

    @endforeach
    <!-- /.card-body -->
    <div class="card-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-12">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

And controller

```
public function hof_switch(Request $request)
{
    foreach ($request->id as $i => $id) {
         $switch = $request->switch;
            if ($request->switch == true) {
                $switch[$i] = "Yes";
            } else {
                $switch[$i] = "No";
            }

        $update = DB::connection('XXX')->table('XXX_HOF')
            ->where('class', $request->class[$i])
            ->update(
                [
                    'status' => $switch[$i],
                ]);
        
    }

    return redirect()->back()->withSuccess('You have switch this class successfully!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you're describing is already baked into the `checkbox` input type.

If the checkbox is checked, it will be sent as part of the form submission and available in the `$request` object and its value can be considered `truthy` (yes). If the checkbox is not checked it will not be sent as part of the form submission and therefore **not** in the `$request` object and so can be considered `falsey` (no).

**Update**

You're making things more complicated than they need to be, make the `value` of your `checkbox` your `$value->id`. Then you can inspect the `$request` object to determine if that `checkbox` was `checked`.

In your blade file:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="switch[]" value="{{ $value->id }}" />
```

In your controller file:

```
public function hof_switch(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->has('switch')) {
        foreach ($request->switch as $checked) {

            // do something ...
            // $checked will be the value of the checkbox, so $value->id

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i do it like u say - `if (!isset($request->switch))
        {
            $switch = "No";
        }` but code dont working, maybe i have error in other code or idk.

Comment: @ВикторМинчев What is not working, what is the error message?

Comment: @Pepermintology `ErrorException
Undefined array key 7 `

Comment: @ВикторМинчев Sounds like you’re looping over an array somewhere and trying to access an element by an array key that doesn’t exist. You’ll need to do some debugging.

Comment: I try but i cant find where is problem.

Comment: @ВикторМинчев Take a look at my update.

Comment: this dont work too. No errors but dont update DB

Comment: @ВикторМинчев You need to fill in the rest ...

Comment: I filled it but it doesn't work

Comment: @ВикторМинчев What doesn’t work? Update your question with your new code and errors.

Answer (score 0):

The value that which checkbox sends to the controller is whether `true` or `false` and you need to check if it's true then use 'yes' else uses 'no':

```
$switch = $request->switch[$i];
if ($switch == true) {
    $switch = "Yes";
} else {
    $switch = "No";
}
```

your code has another problem the switch you used here contains a `yes` or `no` value and it can't be used as an array:

```
// value
$switch = $request->switch;

// Accessing as Array
if ($request->switch == true) {
    $switch[$i] = "Yes";
} else {
    $switch[$i] = "No";
}
```

and this causes the problem.

try to use this:

```
public function hof_switch(Request $request) {
    $count = count(collect($request->get('id')))

    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $switch = $request->switch[$i];

        if ($switch == true) {
            $switch = "Yes";
        } else {
            $switch = "No";
        }

        $update = DB::connection('XXX')->table('XXX_HOF')
            ->where('id', $request->id[$i])
            ->update(
                [
                    'status' => $switch,
                ]);
    }
    return redirect()->back()->withSuccess('You have switch this class successfully!');
}
```

Comment: `ErrorException
Uninitialized string offset 3` now i get this error. I think checkbox is working but problem is in other code and i cant find it :(

Comment: please try to edit your question and attach a more details of the error @ВикторМинчев

Comment: I change first post like u say me to do. But now i get this error. Thats i want is to give result of "Yes" or "No" of all class and update it in db. Example - I have items with 1/ id-1,class-World,status-Yes 2/ id-2,class-TheUniverse,status-No and etc... And i want to update this in DB

Comment: @ВикторМинчев please add the Error text or Image

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/hsOnB8m.png https://i.imgur.com/kDD5dDt.png

Comment: No errors, but dont update DB. When i put "No" its still "Yes" in DB and the opposite.

Comment: @ВикторМинчев I changed the first code as `$switch = $request->switch[$i];
if ($switch == true) {
    $switch = "Yes";
} else {
    $switch = "No";
}` try to review the code again

Comment: W hen i submit with 1 "No" https://i.imgur.com/PEXTV1j.png and error https://i.imgur.com/B522zqJ.png

Comment: @ВикторМинчев I updated the `hof_switch(Request $request)` method and used a for loop instead of foreach the reason was the index of array

Comment: same error in same place :(